# Using a single .txt file to populate many text areas within an HTML form

Tags: javascript, html

I am making an entirely client-side html file that exports .txt files based on the contents of its many text areas and text fields.
The problem arise when I try to import that same .txt file back into the page, as of now its populates all the text areas with the same content while I would like it to only be populated with specific stuff.
E.G. text area 1, 2, and 3 have their contents added to a single .txt file, upon importing it all text areas have content from text area 1, 2 and 3.
Here is my current HTML code

```js
(function() {
 var input = document.getElementById("fileinput");
    input.addEventListener("change", loadFile, false);

    function loadFile() {
        var file, fr;

        if (typeof window.FileReader !== 'function') {
            alert("The file API isn't supported on this browser yet.");
            return;
        }

        if (!input.files) {
            alert("This browser doesn't seem to support the `files` property of file inputs.");
        } else if (!input.files[0]) {
            alert("Please select a file before clicking 'Load'");
        } else {
            file = input.files[0];
            fr = new FileReader();
            fr.onload = receivedText;
            fr.readAsText(file);
        }

        function receivedText() {
   document.getElementById("input1").value = fr.result;
   document.getElementById("input2").value = fr.result;
   document.getElementById("input3").value = fr.result;

        }
    }
})();

function saveFormAsTextFile()
        // Based on https://thiscouldbebetter.wordpress.com/2012/12/18/loading-editing-and-saving-a-text-file-in-html5-using-javascrip/
        {
        var textToSave =
          document.getElementById('input1').value + '\n' +
          document.getElementById('input2').value + '\n' +
    document.getElementById('input3').value

         var textToSaveAsBlob = new Blob([textToSave], {type:"text/plain"});
        var textToSaveAsURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(textToSaveAsBlob);
        var fileNameToSaveAs = document.getElementById("input1").value;

        var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
        downloadLink.download = fileNameToSaveAs;
        downloadLink.innerHTML = "Download File";
        downloadLink.href = textToSaveAsURL;
        downloadLink.onclick = destroyClickedElement;
        downloadLink.style.display = "none";
        document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);

        downloadLink.click();
        }

    function destroyClickedElement(event)
        {
        document.body.removeChild(event.target);
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="saveFormAsTextFile()">Save</button></strong> 
<form name="mainForm" method="get" id="Main">
<p>input 1:<textarea id="input1" cols="20" rows="2"></textarea>
<p>input 2:<textarea id="input2" cols="20" rows="2"></textarea>
<p>input 3:<textarea id="input3" cols="20" rows="2"></textarea>
<p>
   <div>
   <label for="file">Choose file to upload</label>
   <input type="file" id='fileinput' accept=".txt">
 </div>
</form>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The solution is in the code where you write the file. You've to add a "mark", something with which you can separate the parts for the textareas. Then you can split the result using the mark, and populate the textareas from the array the splitting created.

Comment: We need a sample of the text file, but let's say every part are separated by this char: ᯍ then you can just `text.split("ᯍ")` in one of the many iterative way that js provide natively

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You join text with `\n` in

```
  var textToSave =
    document.getElementById('input1').value + '\n' +
    document.getElementById('input2').value + '\n' +
    document.getElementById('input3').value
```

So just reverse step it with `.split('\n')`

```
    function receivedText() {
      var data = fr.result.split('\n');
      document.getElementById("input1").value = data[0];
      document.getElementById("input2").value = data[1];
      document.getElementById("input3").value = data[2];
    }
```

Demo

```js
(function() {
  var input = document.getElementById("fileinput");
  input.addEventListener("change", loadFile, false);

  function loadFile() {
    var file, fr;

    if (typeof window.FileReader !== 'function') {
      alert("The file API isn't supported on this browser yet.");
      return;
    }

    if (!input.files) {
      alert("This browser doesn't seem to support the `files` property of file inputs.");
    } else if (!input.files[0]) {
      alert("Please select a file before clicking 'Load'");
    } else {
      file = input.files[0];
      fr = new FileReader();
      fr.onload = receivedText;
      fr.readAsText(file);
    }

    function receivedText() {
      var data = fr.result.split('\n');
      document.getElementById("input1").value = data[0];
      document.getElementById("input2").value = data[1];
      document.getElementById("input3").value = data[2];
    }
  }
})();

function saveFormAsTextFile()
// Based on https://thiscouldbebetter.wordpress.com/2012/12/18/loading-editing-and-saving-a-text-file-in-html5-using-javascrip/
{
  var textToSave =
    document.getElementById('input1').value + '\n' +
    document.getElementById('input2').value + '\n' +
    document.getElementById('input3').value

  var textToSaveAsBlob = new Blob([textToSave], {
    type: "text/plain"
  });
  var textToSaveAsURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(textToSaveAsBlob);
  var fileNameToSaveAs = document.getElementById("input1").value;

  var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
  downloadLink.download = fileNameToSaveAs;
  downloadLink.innerHTML = "Download File";
  downloadLink.href = textToSaveAsURL;
  downloadLink.onclick = destroyClickedElement;
  downloadLink.style.display = "none";
  document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);

  downloadLink.click();
}

function destroyClickedElement(event) {
  document.body.removeChild(event.target);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <button onclick="saveFormAsTextFile()">Save</button></strong>
  <form name="mainForm" method="get" id="Main">
    <p>input 1:<textarea id="input1" cols="20" rows="2"></textarea>
      <p>input 2:<textarea id="input2" cols="20" rows="2"></textarea>
        <p>input 3:<textarea id="input3" cols="20" rows="2"></textarea>
          <p>
            <div>
              <label for="file">Choose file to upload</label>
              <input type="file" id='fileinput' accept=".txt">
            </div>
  </form>



</body>

</html>
```

Sidenote: file uploading in your code doesn't work in safari

Comment: This code worked like a charm, thank you thank you thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It appears in the function receiveText, you set all three elements to equal the same string, 'fr.result".

You need a way to devide up the content of the txt so you can split it into multiple strings and assign each sub-string to a separate field.

Maybe a simple XML structure would help.